# Django manytomany unique constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my django model:

```
class Reaction(models.Model):
    first_object = models.ForeignKey(Object, related_name='first_object')
    second_object = models.ForeignKey(Object, related_name='second_object')
    result_object = models.ForeignKey(Object, related_name='result_object')
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('first_object', 'second_object',),)
```

I would like to make this unique constraint simultaneously together with

```
unique_together = (('second_object', 'first_object',),)
```

For example, i would not be able to add this object

```
Reaction(first_object__id=2, second_object__id=1)
```

if

```
Reaction(first_object__id=1, second_object__id=2)
```

exists. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to just use `unique_together = ('fist_object', 'second_object')`. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

Comment: May be this question is stupid, but: have you tried `unique_together = (('first_object', 'second_object'), ('second_object', 'first_object'))`?